# Windows 10 Shortcuts Not Working - Windows logo key + Ctrl + number

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

The following shortcut is not working:

**Windows logo key + Ctrl + number** - Open the desktop and switch to the last active window of the app pinned to the taskbar in the position indicated by the number.

See "Windows logo key keyboard shortcuts": https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts

Windows logo key + Ctrl + 5 should open the 5th application icon on the taskbar if no windows are open yet, or if there were multiple windows open it should cycle through them.

**These Windows Logo Key shortcuts work:** The rest of the windows logo key shortcuts work as far as I can tell.

The two-key shortcuts work:

Windows logo key + D

Windows logo key + L

Windows logo key + R

and so on

**Multi-key Windows Logo Key + number combinations work:** Other three-key and four-key combinations work, especially the number ones (but not the one mentioned at the beginning!):

Windows logo key + number - I can properly cycle through the windows with this

Windows logo key + Shift + number - I can open a new instance of an application

Windows logo key + Alt + number - I can open the jump list / the menu pops up

Windows logo key + Ctrl + Shift + number - I can open a new instance of the app as an admin

**The Windows logo key + Ctrl + number shortcut is not working on at least two Windows machines for me**. One is a desktop, and the other is a laptop. The laptop has a docking station and neither the USB keyboard or integral laptop keyboard work with this shortcut. The shortcut used to work on my desktop, but it stopped working at some point in the last year or two.

And fun fact: this shortcut was working for me on a different work laptop in the last two months.

```
Laptop that isn't working Windows version

Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 1809
OS Build 17763.720
```

**The Ctrl, Windows Logo, and number keys all work individually** on the laptop and desktop machines where the shortcut doesn't work. I can't find an answer for this after searching as thoroughly as I can for this sort of question. Shortcut questions are hard to search for.

Comment: In my test this only worked with real number keys, not with numpad keys. Is this the problem?

Comment: @harrymc This is not the issue. I am using the normal number keys. I am not using the numpad number keys.

Comment: Do these keys work when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc I can try later at home. I couldn't boot into safe mode on my work machine. I think because of bitlocker.

Comment: @harrymc Weird, my desktop at home is fine now. It definitely wasn't recently. My work laptop is not, though. I guess I'll have to wait to see if it starts working at some point.

Comment: To detect if this is caused by some installed software, you could try at work to do a [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows).

Comment: @harrymc I tried disabling all of the startup services and items in task manager, but it didn't change the ability to use the shortcut.

Comment: Try the keyboard reset trick: In *Settings > Time & Language > Language*, move another language to the top, reboot, then undo it and reboot. Add a second language of the same family if you only have one.

Comment: @harrymc I changed the default language and rebooted. And then I changed it back to the original default and rebooted, but I am still not having any success with the shortcut. I tried the shortcut each time after changing the language without any success.